# Get type of array in Java annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm writing an annotation processor. How can I get the type of an array?

```
@MyAnnotation
int[] iArray;


@MyAnnotation
boolean[] bArray;


@MyAnnotation
FooClass[] fooArray;
```

As far as I know I can check if it's an array like that:

```
if (element.asType().getKind() == TypeKind.ARRAY) {
   // it's an array
   // How to check if its an array of boolean or an array integer, etc.?
}
```

How do I get the type of the array?

Basically I iterate over all elements annotated with `@MyAnnotation` and I will do something special with Arrays depending on the type of the array, something like that:

```
for (Element element : enviroment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)) {
    if (element.getKind() != ElementKind.FIELD)
        continue;

    if (element.asType().getKind() == TypeKind.ARRAY) {
        // it's an array
        // How to distinguish between array of boolean or an array integer, etc.?
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `Element`?

Comment: Element is `VariableElement`

Comment: do an instaceof check on the first element in the array ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you know it's an array type, you can cast its type to an `ArrayType`.

```
ArrayType asArrayType = (ArrayType) element.asType();
```

`ArrayType` has a `getComponentType()` method, so

```
asArrayType.getComponentType();
```

to get the component type.

You can then repeat the process to get the component type's `TypeKind`.